# Google Maps Ionic Native show blank page in android and ios

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I am new with ionic, I'm trying to integrate a google map in my application with ionic-native-googlemaps. In my browser it works fine but when I build for android or ios I have a blank page, and if I look at the console of google chrome at url chrome://inspect/device I don't have an error.

This is my typescript file

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker,
  Environment, LatLng, GoogleMapOptions
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps/ngx';
import { ActionSheetController, Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-favoris',
  templateUrl: './favoris.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favoris.component.scss'],
})
export class FavorisComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  map: GoogleMap;
  constructor(
    public alertController: AlertController,
    public actionCtrl: ActionSheetController,
    private platform: Platform
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // await this.platform.ready();
    // await this.loadMap();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then( () => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }


  loadMap() {

    const map = GoogleMaps.create('map');

    map.one( GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY ).then( ( data: any ) => {

      const coordinates: LatLng = new LatLng( 45.649864, -73.584213 );
      const position = {
        target: coordinates,
        zoom: 14
      };

      map.animateCamera( position );

      const markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
        position: coordinates,
        // icon: "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png",
        title: 'Hello California',
        draggable: true
      };

      const marker = map.addMarker( markerOptions )
        .then( ( markesr: Marker ) => {
          markesr.showInfoWindow();
        });

    });
  }
}
```

And in my html file I have

```
<ion-app>
    <ion-header translucent>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title>List</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
        <ion-toolbar class="new-background-color">
            <ion-title class="text-center text-white">Favoris</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <div id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

I have searched for a solution everywhere but I have not found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly i solve my problem, if someone have a same problem later,
just downgrade a version ionic-google maps and ionic core like this

```
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.24.0",
"@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.0.0-beta.20",
```

After that look if your div with who contains google if is have a 500px height or more if it's ok, your map workly fine and you need to paid google map too.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to downgrade googleMap .
there is two way to solve this problem :

First you can put the tag DIV outside ion-content

```
 <div id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
      <ion-content>

    </ion-content>
```

OR you can add style css to put the content background transparant to overlaye the map  screen.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was showing right on Android but no IOS. API key was ok. The map was there, under the html, but ion-content was not transparent.

Try adding this to your global scss or css file.

```
._gmap_cdv_ {
     --background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS and Chrome, if your application has 'location' function. Apple is serious about location security aspect and Google Chrome is also somewhat serious about it. Hence:

1. Step 1. In your Mac enable 'Location Services' under 'Security and Privacy' :
   Navigate to 'Settings'=>'Security & Privacy'=>Privacy Tab=>Select
   Location Services ; click the padlock to make changes=>make sure
   checkbox is checked for Google Chrome
2. Step 2. In Google Chrome go
   to Settings=>privacy & Security=>make sure localhost:8100 is in the
   'allowed' list=>click on it and on the next tab 'Reset permissions'
   and select 'Allow' in the drop-down box for location property.

That should do it.